# Excel VBA how to select all cells in a dynamic range were the colour index is not 0

Tags: vba, excel

I have a SAP Report embedded in a worksheet, it is refreshed via a macro using variables defined in another worksheet. That all works fine, but i am having trouble selecting the data the report generates.

The headings of the report are in and always will fall in this range `("A17:K17")`, but the results rows will vary making the total range I want to capture anywhere from `("A17:K18")` to `(A17:K1000")`.

The solutions I've already tried didn't work i think because there is almost no consistency in the result data, it's a mixture of text and numbers with empty cells all over the place, in both the rows and columns. Including the occasional completely empty row. This means the methods I have tried before reach a point where it thinks it's reached the end of the populated rows - but it hasn't.

The only factor that remains the same throughout the report is that the cells in the range I want to capture are all filled with a color as default and anything outside the range is unfilled.

To me the simplest solution would be to use VBA to select all the cells beneath and including the headers on `("A17:K17")`  where the color index is not 0 (blank?) regardless of their contents as I don't mind capturing empty cells. Except I don't know how to do this.

At this point I'd just like to select this range I haven't decided if I'm going to copy it into a new workbook or into an email yet, but that I can do. I've just hit a dead end selecting it.

Comment: tried `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address`? Also `If [A1].Interior.ColorIndex <> xlColorIndexNone Then` -> is coloured.

Comment: And where is the problem in checking the ColorIndex in a VBA Sub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite unsure *exactly* what it is you require but here's a solution. It's worth noting that both the ColorIndex and Color properties are not necessarily zero with no fill, so if you just change *blankCell* to a cell with the fill which you define to be blank you'll be good to go.

```
Sub test()
Set blankCell = Range("A1")    ' change this to a cell that you define to be blank
blankIndex = blankCell.Interior.Color
Set cellsDesired = Range("A17:K17")
For Each cell In Range("A17:K1000")
    If cell.Interior.Color <> blankIndex Then
        Set cellsDesired = Application.Union(cellsDesired, Range(cell.Address))
    End If
Next cell
cellsDesired.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, That worked absolutely perfectly!